# Deploying an express server on Heroku

Tags: express, heroku

My express server looks something like this:

```
//server.js
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, ...


   // this is further wrapped in main.js
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

var child = new (forever.Monitor)('server/server.js', {
  max: 30000,
  silent: false,
  args: []
});

  child.start();
```

When I deploy to heroku I currently execute main.js

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server/main.js"
  },
```

so far so good... 
heroku starts off forever which further starts off my express server..

However I don't believe I am getting the full advantage of running the express server on all the cores ..

Ideally i would like to do something pm2 to start my express server. 
How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

When deploying code to Heroku, you DO NOT want to use a process monitor like pm2 or forever -- this is because Heroku's dyno grid will automatically detect application crashes and handle restarting your processes. This is a more reliable way to handle things as you'll also get useful Heroku debug information in the logs.

**NOTE**: I also noticed in your example that you're listening for connections on port 3000 -- you probably don't want to do this on Heroku, as they assign you a port to listen on randomly. You should say `app.listen(process.env.PORT);` instead.

Comment: pm2 also ensures that the node app is using all the available cores.. how does Heroku's dyno grid handle this ?

Comment: You typically DON'T want to use all the cores on a Heroku dyno -- the CPU resources are typically pretty constrained -- even with a single Node process you'll likely be able to use up a lot of CPU cycles. If you really want to do that, you can, but please be careful of your CPU utilization. I've noticed this going crazy myself. The Dyno grid itself is meant to scale horizontally. So if you cap out one Dyno, just add another.

Comment: could you pls expand on "The Dyno grid itself is mean to scale horizontally". What does that mean ?

Comment: Basically, when you add additional dynos to your app, Heroku automatically load balances incoming requests to them evenly. This means that your application will scale across many dynos (web servers). There's no need to limit yourself to a single server. Instead: you're meant to spin up multiple dynos, this way you get more CPU / RAM / bandwidth resources.

Comment: This is only partly true. The answer is right for free, hobby, standard-1x dynos (1 cluster worker recommended). 
But Heroku Dev Center sais that you should care about concurrency, to use all CPU cores on "performance-M" and "performance-L" dynos (up to 28 workers):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-concurrency

Comment: Correct -- but to do this you want to use node cluster (not a process manager like PM2). Otherwise you'll still have the original problem :(